# Finding minimal distance between objects from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables, both contain objects with XY coordinates:

Table A:

```
ID_A | X    | Y
-----|------|------
100  | 32.2 | 25.6
101  | 36.2 | 22.1
102  | 31.7 | 39.2
103  | 42.7 | 15.6
104  | 24.5 | 29.9
```

Table B:

```
ID_B | X    | Y
-----|------|------
200  | 55.3 | 25.1
201  | 21.5 | 54.2
202  | 67.3 | 66.6
203  | 23.5 | 55.4
204  | 41.1 | 24.5
205  | 42.4 | 62.6
206  | 26.8 | 23.6
207  | 63.2 | 25.6
208  | 35.6 | 11.1
209  | 74.2 | 22.2
210  | 12.2 | 33.3
211  | 15.7 | 44.4
```

For each object in table A, I want to find the nearest object in table B (the distance between objects is minimal).
So the result should be like this (the distances are random here...):

```
ID_A | ID_B | DISTANCE
-----|------|---------
100  | 203  | 12.5
101  | 203  | 11.1
102  | 211  | 16.5
103  | 205  | 14.2
104  | 209  | 17.7
```

The distance between objects:

```
SQRT( (A.X-B.X)*(A.X-B.X) + (A.Y-B.Y)*(A.Y-B.Y) )
```

So I made this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID_A
     , FIRST_VALUE (B.ID_B) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID_A ORDER BY SQRT((A.X-B.X)*(A.X-B.X)+(A.Y-B.Y)*(A.Y-B.Y)) ASC) AS ID_B
     , FIRST_VALUE (SQRT((A.X-B.X)*(A.X-B.X)+(A.Y-B.Y)*(A.Y-B.Y))) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID_A ORDER BY SQRT((A.X-B.X)*(A.X-B.X)+(A.Y-B.Y)*(A.Y-B.Y)) ASC) AS DISTANCE
FROM TableA A, TableB B
```

It works like it should, but the problem is that both tables have a huge amount of rows (over 500k) and this query is rather slow (and probably very inefficient).

How to optimize this query? (I am using Oracle SQL)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finding the shortest distance squared is the same as finding the shortest distance, so you could safely drop `SQRT` from the `partition` and `order by` clauses. This should speed up the calculations a little.

Comment: Thanks. It did speed up things - a little ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like dasblinkenlight mentioned, since the rows with the shortest distance squared will also be those with the shortest distance, you don't need to calculate the square root for every combination of rows.

I think your best best is trying to reduce the overall number of calculations performed, so maybe something like this will speed things up:

```
SELECT ID_A,ID_B,SQRT(DISTANCE_SQUARED) DISTANCE FROM (
  SELECT ID_A,ID_B,DISTANCE_SQUARED,MIN(DISTANCE_SQUARED) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_A) MIN_DS FROM (
    SELECT A.ID_A,B.ID_B,
    POWER(A.X-B.X,2)+POWER(A.Y-B.Y,2) DISTANCE_SQUARED
    FROM
    TABLE_A A,
    TABLE_B B
  )
)
WHERE DISTANCE_SQUARED=MIN_DS
```

This may return multiple matches (if more than 1 row in TABLE_B has the same distance from a row in TABLE_A)... not sure if that is acceptable or not.

If the tables are not written to very often and you need to run this query frequently, you may be better off precalculating this info and storing it in another table, say TABLE_C.  When/if a row is added or edited to either table, you can check that one row against the 500k in the other table and update TABLE_C if necessary, rather than needing to check 500k * 500k rows each time you run the query.

Comment: This didn't change much in speed, but this code seems much nicer. Also good idea on storing results in separate table.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think I prefer 'pre-computing' the distance in a CTE.  I know the optimizer is supposed to be able to cache certain values, but I'm not sure how well it might be doing that.  Plus, this makes it easier to maintain based on the 'distance'.  Unfortunately, you don't have a 'maximum distance' to be able to initially exclude certain values, which means that this will *always* be somewhat slower.

```
WITH Distances (id_a, id_b, distance_squared, index) as 
                   (SELECT a.id_a, b.id_b, 
                           POWER((a.x - b.x), 2) + POWER((a.y - b.y), 2) d,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id_a, ORDER BY d ASC)
                    FROM TableA a
                    CROSS JOIN TableB b)
SELECT id_a, id_b,
       SQRT(distance_squared)
FROM Distances
WHERE index = 1
```

Use of `FIRST_VALUE()` is causing the 'smallest' values to repeat - removing them absolves you of the need for `DISTINCT`, which may help some.

---

## EDIT:

If you have a 'maximum distance', try this:

```
WITH Distances (id_a, id_b, distance_squared, index) as 
                   (SELECT a.id_a, b.id_b, 
                           POWER((a.x - b.x), 2) + POWER((a.y - b.y), 2) d,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id_a, ORDER BY d ASC)
                    FROM TableA a
                    JOIN TableB b
                      ON (b.x > a.x - @distance AND b.x < a.x + @distance)
                         AND (b.y > a.y - @distance AND b.y < a.y + @distance)
                    WHERE d < POWER(@distance, 2))
SELECT id_a, id_b,
       SQRT(distance_squared) as distance
FROM Distances
WHERE index = 1
```

This *might* be able to use indices on the coordinate values, although I'm not sure (`TableB` side, probably, `TableA` side... uncertain.  Swap comparisons if necessary).
Note two things here:

1. All of this is presuming you're operating on a flat Cartesian plane.  If this is for points on the earth's surface, the equation is considerably more complex; there's plenty of questions/answers here covering them though, if you look.
2. You still have to get/use the square-root distance, because otherwise you have stuff hiding in the corners of the grid squares, which is actually 'outside' the distance (by about 40%).

Comment: This didn't change much in speed, but code is nicer. Let's say I have a maximum distance, should I use it in a `WHERE` clause after `CROSS JOIN` ? Also, the actual numbers are something like 545632.04536, I used `TRUNC` to trim them down to 545632, but change in speed was minimal.

Answer (score 0):

IF YOUR TABLES DO NOT HAVE CORRESPONDING/MATCHING ROWS DO NOT USE JOIN AT ALL. USE TWO SEPARATE QUERIES. OTHERWISE YOUR OUTPUT WILL CONTAIN 500K * 500K ROWS. I assumed your tables are related in my example and all I'm doing is trying to help.

And see Outer Join below.

Unless you made a mistake in your final query example while copying it into your post your query running long because you doubling the result forgetting to join tables a and b. What you get is Cartesian product:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID_A
 , FIRST_VALUE (B.ID_B) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID_A ORDER BY SQRT((A.X-B.X)*(A.X-B.X)+(A.Y-B.Y)*(A.Y-B.Y)) ASC) AS ID_B
 , FIRST_VALUE (SQRT((A.X-B.X)*(A.X-B.X)+(A.Y-B.Y)*(A.Y-B.Y))) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID_A ORDER BY SQRT((A.X-B.X)*(A.X-B.X)+(A.Y-B.Y)*(A.Y-B.Y)) ASC) AS DISTANCE
 FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE a.id = b.id -- You missed this
/
```

Besides this, you are using DISTINCT. Try adding join and drop distinct and see the difference. Let all rows be selected and note the execution/elapsed time. General example on avoiding distinct based on emp table:

```
-- Distinct - runs longer --
SELECT DISTINCT d.deptno, dname FROM scott.dept D, scott.emp E WHERE D.deptno = E.deptno
/  
-- Same as Distinct - faster --
SELECT deptno, dname FROM scott.dept D 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM scott.emp E WHERE E.deptno = D.deptno)
/
```

OUTER JOIN. Below query will return all rows from A table (dept) table and B  even if B does not have corresponding row in table A. Run the query and see deptno = 40. It has no rows in emp tablr and null is displayed for empname. Your table A (scott.dept in my example) seems to hasve less rows then B (emp. in my example). So, outer join is the answer I think:

```
SELECT d.deptno, e.ename
  FROM scott.dept d LEFT OUTER JOIN scott.emp e
    ON d.deptno = e.deptno
ORDER BY d.deptno
/
```

Comment: ... Umm, given that `TableA.id` **!=** `TableB.id`, the join condition isn't going to help at all.  In fact, he _needs_ the Cartesian product, because he's getting the shortest distance between different points - he doesn't have anything else to join them with!  Now, the `DISTINCT` can probably just be removed, as the given tuples should be unique _regardless_, which should help some.  But I doubt this is the full story...

Comment: @Clockwork- It is all up to the user. Only user knows the full story. The Outer Join maybe the answer...

Comment: Thats right, the Cartesian product is what I need. When I don't use DISTINCT, I get multiple identical entries. Could you elaborate your thoughts on OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @user2051102 - sorry, I mis-conceptualized what `FIRST_VALUE()` was actually doing, it's obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @Art: -1 - Given that the _example_ **EXPLICITLY SHOWS** that 'joined' rows don't have matching ids, I'd say it's not 'up to the user'.  In fact, if you'll notice, _none_ of the rows in `TableB` have ids matching `TableA` ids.  If the ids _did_ match, I'd expect the distance to be `0`... which would be worthless.

Comment: @Clockwork - Look, lets not get ridiculous here. If there are no rows that match in tables then user made a mistake. There should simply be two separate queries. Otherwise the output of 500K will be multiplied by another 500K. This is SQL basics.

Comment: @All who interested in addition to my posts - Cross joining tables that have 500K rows in real world is NOT possible. No one would even think about this. And I'm in real world. Sorry for my stereotypes and assumptions, I just cannot imagine such thing in real world.

Comment: Yes, it is; however, think about this: You have a table of friends and their locations, and a list of restaurants and their locations.  Your friends keep asking you to come to the 'closest restaurant'... Any 'matching' ids between restaurants/friends are immaterial - they shouldn't be compared (they refer to different things).  The output of this type of query represents a 'static' list you might keep in your wallet, so you're ready no matter which friend calls you.

Comment: @Clockwork- Sorry, dude... As I wrote I'm in real world, at real job, doing this because I'm bored and learning at the same time. It is NOT possible to cross join tables with 500K records in real world. You'd be soooooooo... fired for this. So, I made an assumptions that tables are related, as in real world. If not then two sep. queries is an answer. Please do not downvote people from the real world. Forgive us our stereotypes...